# JavaScript - How to call prototype function from another function (non prototype)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, prototype

I want to call current instance prototype function from a dynamically created function, but I cannot make it. I use Google Firebase [Friendly Chat example](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/#0).

Here is the JS file.

```
// Initializes FriendlyChat.
var chat = "test";

function FriendlyChat() {
  this.checkSetup();
  $("#l_chat").html("");
  this.initFirebase();


//LOAD ALL CHATs
this.database1 = firebase.database();

this.messagesRef1 = this.database1.ref('messages/');

this.messagesRef1.on("child_added", function(snapshot, prevChildKey)        {
 var newPost = snapshot.val();
  console.log(newPost);
 var name1 = String(snapshot.key);
 document.getElementById("l_chat").innerHTML  += '<button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-color-text--white" onclick="click1(\'' + name1 + '\');"><i class="material-icons">chat</i><span>' +
 snapshot.key + '</span></button><br/>';
});



}

// Sets up shortcuts to Firebase features and initiate firebase auth.
FriendlyChat.prototype.initFirebase = function() {
  // Shortcuts to Firebase SDK features.
  this.auth = firebase.auth();
  this.database = firebase.database();
  this.storage = firebase.storage();
  // Initiates Firebase auth and listen to auth state changes.
  this.auth.onAuthStateChanged(this.onAuthStateChanged.bind(this));
};
// Loads chat messages history and listens for upcoming ones.
FriendlyChat.prototype.loadMessages = function() {
this.messagesRef = this.database.ref('messages/' + chat);

  // Make sure we remove all previous listeners.
  this.messagesRef.off();
  $("#messages").html("");
  // Loads the last 15 messages and listen for new ones.
  var setMessage = function(data) {
    var val = data.val();
    this.displayMessage(data.key, val.name, val.text, val.photoUrl, val.imageUrl);
  }.bind(this);
  this.messagesRef.limitToLast(15).on('child_added', setMessage);
  this.messagesRef.limitToLast(15).on('child_changed', setMessage);
};


function click1(name) {
chat = name;
console.log ('test works ' + chat);
this.loadMessages(); // here is the problem!!!!
};



window.onload = function() {
  window.friendlyChat = new FriendlyChat();
};
```

So as you can see, I dynamically create `click1` function and I want when I click an object to reload the messages, I want to access `FriendlyChat.prototype.loadMessages`.

What I already tried?

```
this.loadmessages();
```

and

```
FriendlyChat.prototype.loadMessages();
```

But they are not working. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Maybe `window.friendlyChat.loadMessages()` ?

Comment: @rbntd you almost never need to reference the window object, as you can reach it's contents from the globak scope. window.a is equal to a

Comment: Your actual problem is using inline html event handler attributes that can call global functions (like `friendly1`) only. Use a proper event listener and a closure.